# How to center background images on window resize?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using this tutorial http://www.queness.com/resources/html/scroll/horizontal.html to help me to create my own website, and I have an issue with it.

I want to add  specific background images for each page and I wish images remain centered in the pages, regardless of window size and screen resolution. for now I made my images in a resolution of 1920x1080, and when I resized my browser window, the images move and stack up in a strange way.

Is there a way to make these background images to always stay in place and not move when I resize the window?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Luna, we cannot properly help you without seeing some code. it would be just guessing... mass of comments and inaccurate answers. If you're looking just for a link. you're on the wrong place. Welcome to StackOverflow! ;)

Comment: Well, I was not sure of wich part of my cide I needed to post to get a proper answer. I mean, was it in the html, css or jquery part. I only started to learn that a few months ago, soI didn't dare posting the entire code! But I found my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial shows how to do what you're looking for.  The only downside is that the earliest version of IE is works in is 9.

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Thanks to you! Your answer was not really the good one, but it really helped me to look in the good direction an now it works, In fact, I put the background images for each page in the css code, with a center position.

Comment: The big secret was in that first block and the first line of code. Congrats to getting it working.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your css- `img{margin:auto;}`

Comment: Sorry, didn't work for me, but still it hleped me to find a solution to my issue. Thanks anymay!